# How do I post back information from a webpage that has post-generated content?

Tags: c#, html, html-lists

Ok so I am very new to html and the web. Right now I am trying to generate list items on the fly and then have them post back to the web server so I know what the person is trying to obtain.

Here is the code for generating the list items:

```
foreach (var item in dataList) {
    MyDataList.InnerHtml += "<li><a runat='server' onclick='li_Click' id='" + item.Name + "-button'></a></li>";
}
```

Further down I have my click event.

```
protected void li_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //How do I determine here which item was actually clicked?
}
```

My question is how do I determine which list item was clicked?

Btw, the code running behind is C#.

**EDIT 1**

```
LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
link.ID = "all-button";
link.Text = "All";
link.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);
MyDataList.Controls.Add(link);
```

Then below I have my link_Click event that never seems to hit a breakpoint.

```
void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (sender != null) {
        if (sender.GetType() == typeof(LinkButton)) {
            LinkButton button = (LinkButton)sender;
            if (button.ID == "all-button") {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know this has to be possible I just cant figure out what I am missing.

**Edit 2**

Ok ok I think I know what the problem is. I was trying to add a second list inside of another list. This was causing the whole thing to have problems. It is working now.

Comment: The fact you added "runat='server' and "id" properties does not mean they will be server controls. You should add LinkButtons controls if you want them to be server controls. I will add an example now.

Comment: Are you using the asp.net web forms DataList?

Comment: @prashantht No I am trying to stay away from .NET Web Controls as much as possible right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using LinkButtons.

Code Behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    LinkButton link = new LinkButton() { ID = "link_" + i };
    link.Text = "Link " + i;
    link.Click+=new EventHandler(link_Click);
    this.Form.Controls.Add(link);
}

protected void link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Every time a link is clicked it will get here in the server side
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I will give this a go tomorrow. So when I receive the link_Click I could cast the sender back to a LinkButton and then get my text correct?

Comment: Exactly, all you need is a parent container to add the linkbutton children.

Comment: I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I have added the code exactly as it is above. However, when I debug it does nothing when I click the link. Oddly enough I have other buttons that can be clicked and it operate just fine. These buttons and their click events are registered before compile time though.

Comment: It does. However, now I have run into another problem. Because the server controls are dynamically created. When it posts back its running the page load event too and not just the click event. Is it possible to get rid of that?

Comment: @meanbunny, every postback will trigger the page_load event. If you do not want some of the code to be executed you will have to put it inside an "if" statement and use the __EVENTTARGET variable to know which control caused the postback.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13386/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-meanbunny)

Answer (score -1):

you can easily do this

```
onclick='li_Click(this)'
```

EDIT:-
after the edited content
you will have to create all the controls on server side in pageLoad() to get the click event on the server side.. also a lot more client side script would be needed..
i think youll be better of calling a javascript function and then using $.get or $.post to send the data back to the server

Comment: Is this for C#? I tried adding that to my foreach loop and it didn't seem to make a different.

Comment: naaah this is just plain JavaScript